# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'poll'

Tags: python, linux, gevent, greenlets, filesystem-events

Trying to use gevent.select.poll for monitoring something under /sys. The below code works fine when using native Python. When i use gevent and do

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

from gevent import select  
p = select.poll()
p.register(fd, select.POLLERR | select.POLLPRI)

while True:
   if p.poll():
      <do something>
```

Tried using select.select.poll() or tried importing gevent directly. However, it keeps throwing "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'poll'". or it keeps throwing:

```
 from gevent.select import poll
 ImportError: cannot import name poll
```

Am i missing anything here ? From gevent code, i see poll class. https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/src/gevent/select.py

Comment: I can run the code. Which version of `gevent` does this code use?

Comment: @michael I am using 1.2, which version are you using ?

Comment: You were able to run this, you mean: >>> from gevent import select
>>> p = select.poll()

Comment: @user9763248: 1.2 is from [2016](https://www.gevent.org/whatsnew_1_2.html), which is far behind what you see in the master branch on github.